# Cambiar función del botón "atrás" en Android

Tags: android, kotlin, onbackpressed

Quiero cambiar la función del botón atrás que viene integrado en Android. Me gustaría que al presionarlo estando en la activity principal mostrase un cuadro de diálogo informando de que se va a cerrar la aplicación y que el usuario pueda decidir si hacerlo o no, en lugar de que vaya a la activity anterior.

Según he estado buscando esto hay que hacerlo en la Mainactivity pero ni siquiera llega a mostrarse el cuadro de diálogo con el siguiente código:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed()
    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity)
    builder.setMessage("Quieres salir?")
        .setCancelable(false)

}
```

¿Podéis echarme un cable? También necesitaría el código que hace cerrar la aplicación. Muchas gracias.

Solucionado con el siguiente código:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
        AlertDialog.Builder(this@Activity1)
            .setMessage("¿Salir de la aplicación?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Si") { dialog, whichButton ->
                finishAffinity() //Sale de la aplicación.
            }
            .setNegativeButton("Cancelar") { dialog, whichButton ->

            }
            .show()
    }
```

Comment: Primero, yo no estaría viendo que muestres el `Alert`, segundo para evitar esa acción deberías quitar la línea `super.onBackPressed()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No llames `super.onBackPressed()` si no hasta que determines que en realidad deseas salir, simplemente construye el dialogo realizando lo siguiente:

```
 override fun onBackPressed() {
        AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity)
            .setMessage("Quieres salir?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Ok") { dialog, whichButton ->
                super.onBackPressed() //Sale de Activity.
            }
            .setNegativeButton("Cancelar") { dialog, whichButton ->

            }
            .show()
    }
```

el dialogo se mostraría de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La solución funciona pero no quiero que cierre el activity, si no que cierre la aplicación entera. ¿Como podría hacer esto? Muchas gracias.

Comment: La única solución es que esto se ponga en MainActivity y llamar  finishAffinity() ya que no hay forma de cerrar una aplicación completamente desde otra Actividad. Recuerda que si tienes duda diferente puedes realizar otra pregunta haciendo referencia a esta.

Comment: El problema es que tengo el login en el MainActivity y no quiero que se vea, con esta función se cierra el activity y vuelve al MainActivity y si pulso nuevamente hacia atrás se muestra la splashscreen, lo cual queda muy feo para la experiencia del usuario.

Comment: Necesitas agregar flags cuando abres tu Splash, login y main activity

Answer (score -2):

Solucionado con el siguiente código:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
        AlertDialog.Builder(this@Activity1)
            .setMessage("¿Salir de la aplicación?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Si") { dialog, whichButton ->
                finishAffinity() //Sale de la aplicación.
            }
            .setNegativeButton("Cancelar") { dialog, whichButton ->

            }
            .show()
    }
```

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).

Comment: Otra cosa, este codigo es exactamente igual al de la otra respuesta. Deberias haber aceptado la otra respuesta, y si habia algun detalle, solucionarlo en los comentarios o pedirle a quien te dio la respuesta que agregara eso.